# Increasing form input width for a position absolute element in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to increase the width of an input element of a form group in Bootstrap 3. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19740070/3136225) I can control the width by applying the `col` property to the div containing the input element.

The form has position absolute and I think that's what's stopping it from changing the width. Removing the position absolute allows me to increase the width. How can I increase the width of the element?

Here is my code

```
<form id="search_bar" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="dj-search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Search favourite DJs" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeycD/444/) for the same.

Comment: setting a width works on your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MeycD/446/

Comment: @Vector That's weird. If I try the same thing in my project, it just moves the entire div to the right with that width but the input element width remains the same.

Comment: If you post a link i could have a quick look

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of your two `.form-control` class to the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add 'left' with 'right'. Like this. Adjust width with left and right.

```
#search_bar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  left:40px;
}
```

[Here is your fiddle with changes made](http://jsfiddle.net/MeycD/1518/)