# How to set width for edit controls in mvc5

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have code below that creates form with a Dropdown and edit. How can I set width for each individually.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal" style="background-color:azure">
         <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I tried below , but it dosen't work.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "Width:250px"  } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap, why not use it to control the size?
Here is an answer about it.
[Input widths on Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539711/input-widths-on-bootstrap-3)

Or you can create a class with defined sizes and apply these classes.

Comment: Thanks Luiz . I am really new to all this.  Will look into provided link.