# dropdown list width is not exact with content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap library to set styles on dropdown selection `class="form-control input-sm"`

but my problem is the content of the drop list is 'cut' I cant see the whole value, if i remove it it back to native style which not my goal

i was trying to get some answer to previous post but no luck finding quick solution on this? any thoughts?

[image]

thanks,

Comment: [Probably similar question and answer to it - see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539711/input-widths-on-bootstrap-3)

Comment: do u have your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code and put your menu options to this ul.

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Small button <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
...
</ul>
</div>
```

As you can read from their docs its not advised to style inputs with bootstrap classes because their behaviour is different on vaious browsers.