# Adjust input width with bootstrap class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've created a form with using just bootstrap classes. The only problem I don't know how to solve is how to adjust width of input elements on the form?
I know I can use inline styling or write custom css class, but is there a way that I can adjust width of both inputs with using only bootstrap classes?

I would like to adjust width of both inputs to be approximately same as buttons with arrows up / down. Basically I would like to shrink both inputs.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





  <br/>
  
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Nazaj</button>
</div>


  
  <div class="btn-group col-sm-offset-1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
</div>

  
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>
</div>

  
  <div class="btn-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>



<div class="btn-group">
<h1>/</h1>
</div>



<div class="btn-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
</div>

  
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" ></span></button>
</div>
 
<div class="btn-group col-sm-offset-1">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Shrani</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input widths on Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539711/input-widths-on-bootstrap-3)

Comment: I don't think so. I have inline elements. Buttons and inputs in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap grid like

```
<div class="btn-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2" />
</div>
```

Read this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Can you use this on my exaple, please. If I try this code, nothing happens

Comment: You are right. Grid system makes it easy to put elements inline and with desired width. The only thing is outer div, which has to have f.e. class="col-sm-2"

Comment: Yes, you have to code accordingly in grid or just reduce width of input class form-control from css