# Responsive Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap.
I have the following bootstrap form:

```
<form class="form-inline " style="display: inline-block">

   <div class="form-group" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail"  placeholder="full names..."
                                    style="margin: 25px">
   </div>



   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email address..."style="margin: 25px">
   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Sign Up</button>

</form>
```

I want to make the text box wider: When I custom style the width then it ceases to be responsive for small windows. The width doesn’t collapse to fit the small screens.

Your suggestion below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <form class="form-inline " style="display: inline-block">



        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter full names..." style="margin: 25px;width:400px">
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email address..." style="margin: 25px;width:400px">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Sign Up</button>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this stackover question can help you.[inputwidth in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539711/input-widths-on-bootstrap-3)

Comment: hangon your suggestion seems to have worked ..must have been cache thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your provided [website](http://all41web.co.za/designs/test/signup.html), you are breaking the responsiveness by using **fixed** `margin: 25px;` and `width: 300px;`

I would solve it by using media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 430px) {
  input {
    margin: 25px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

the breakpoint is specific for your case! Generally, I would recommend the [bootstrap breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<form class="form-inline " style="display: inline-block">
<div class="form-group" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail" placeholder="full names..." style="margin: 25px">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email address..."style="margin: 25px">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Sign Up</button>
 </form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Messy but it can do the Job!

Comment: I have applied your suggestions bur i have also applied my desired width in the input text box. see below:

Comment: see this link and try make screen smaller
http://all41web.co.za/designs/test/signup.html