# White bar on right side with bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to render a navbar with a selection of links (LI elements) and a right hand search box that isn't collapsed but instead shows underneath on small screens.

The code below *almost* works in that it presents the search bar seperately and underneath the collapsed nav as desired. I am struggling to identify the exact cause or resolution. It seems that if a container is placed immediately underneath the nav element I only get the bar when the navbar collapses.

Navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Food</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" action="/results/" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/item/food/">foods</a></li>
        <li><a href="/item/wine/">wines</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/">admin</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Reviewd the following but none of the solutions seemed to fix my problem
[Twitter bootstrap white gap on right side of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704893/twitter-bootstrap-white-gap-on-right-side-of-page)

Comment: So what is the problem/question? What's wrong with the current solution? Seems to work as expected: http://www.codeply.com/go/FJDpoadCUd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be coming from the navbar-form. Try to wrap it in a div with a col-xs-12 class:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <form class="navbar-form " action="/results/" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

This should fix the problem.