# MDbootstrap massive whitespace on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, mdbootstrap

I'm currently working on a Watch2Gether clone that looks fine on medium and large devices, but once you get to the phone view, everything looks awesome until you scroll left and find a massive whitespace on the right side. I'm not too sure why this is happening, I tried changing the margin and padding on some items which helped with the UI, but there's still a huge whitespace when you scroll which looks really bad. Any idea how to fix this?

[image: Issue shown, there's a big white space on the right side.]

HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <!-- Description -->
    <meta name="description" content="Watch Youtube videos live with your friends, easily, for free!">
    <!-- Favicon  -->
<link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>Room</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">WatchWithFriends</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/create">Create Room</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>

            <input autocomplete="off" id="paste" name="paste" class="form-control form-control-md"placeholder="Paste Video URL Here" aria-label="Search">
            <button id="watch" class="btn btn-outline-success waves-effect" type="submit">Watch</button>
          
        </div>
      </nav>

<div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 main-section">
      <h1 id="roomBasic"><span id="name"></span><span id="users"></span></h1>
          <div id="player"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
      <div id="chat-holder">
      <div id="mario-chat">
        <a id="leave" href="/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg leave">Leave Room</a>
        <div id="chat-window">
          <div id="output"></div>
          <div id="feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <form action="" id="chat-form">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="message"
            placeholder="Message"
            required
            autocomplete="off"
            class="form-control form-control-lg"
          />
          <button class="btn btn-black btn-block" id="send" onclick="reload()">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3 id="welcome-room">Welcome to your room!</h3>
      <p class="room-info-p">
        To invite a friend, just copy the link below. To change their name they
        just have to replace the name in the "username" field. Ex:
        username=Billy -> username=Ryan. They can also join using the "Join Room" page.
      </p>

      
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="urlInfo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Url">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button onclick="copyUrl()" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark m-0 px-3 py-2 z-depth-0 waves-effect" type="button" id="button-addon2">Copy</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p class="room-info-p">To play a new video, paste the URL into the form in the navigation bar and press watch!</p>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.9.4/qs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="client.js"></script>
<script src="users.js"></script>



<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

CSS:

```
    /* room page  */
    
    #name {
      color: #575ed8;
    }
    
    #roomBasic {
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .section {
      height: 80vh;
    }
    
    #mario-chat {
      max-width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    
    #chat-holder {
      margin: 11vh 3vh;
    }
    
    
    #chat-window {
      height: 50vh;
      overflow: auto;
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    #sentText {
      padding: 14px 0px;
      margin: 0 20px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
      color: #555;
    }
    
    #sentText p {
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      margin-bottom: 0.1px;
    }
    
    #feedback p {
      color: #aaa;
      padding: 14px 0px;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }
    
    #output strong {
      color: #575ed8;
    }
    
    #mario-chat input {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: #eee;
      border: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    #send {
      background-color: #292b2c;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 18px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 12px 0;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    }
    
    #player {
      margin: 30px 30px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      height: 62vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .main-section h1 {
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .info {
      margin: 30px 30px;
    }
    
    .leave {
      background: #575ed8;
      font-size: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    /* info section */
    
    .info {
      height: 50vh;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    }
    
    #welcome-room {
      font-weight: 600;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the  same  issue and this  meta  tag belon  helped me  :

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=320, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />`

Or
//from another topic

It is true that the row class is what is causing the issue, but that is because it is always supposed to be placed inside a container element.

from http://getbootstrap.com/css/ :

Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

The container element usually has a -15px padding on both right and left and the row class has a 15px padding on right and left. The two cancel each other out. If one of the two is not present you will see extra space.

From : [Twitter bootstrap white gap on right side of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704893/twitter-bootstrap-white-gap-on-right-side-of-page)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it didn't work. I have a feeling there's a problem with the way I've laid the page out, but I'm not too sure in this case.

Comment: Check the link  in  my  answer topic about the  same  issue

Comment: There was a bit of whitespace on full size devices which your solution did fix, but it's still there on mobile.

Comment: I was able to fix it! Turns out I had set the width of the input to 100vh when the screen-size was reduced to mobile-view, making it way too big. All I had to do was change it to 100% along with your .container solution.